# Firebase Admin SDK: Set / Merge Custom User Claims

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Does Firebase have any trick like `{ merge: true }` to set extra/more **custom claims** without **delete/override** the old variables?

**Step to reproduce:**

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { a: 'value' }) // Run this first
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { b: 'value' }) // Then run this after
```

**Result:**

```
{ b: 'value'}
```

**Expected result**:

```
{ a: 'value', b: 'value' }
```

*Or I did something wrong?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Firebase documentation for [`setCustomUserClaims`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#set-custom-user-claims) states:

> - **customUserClaims**: *Object*
>   The developer claims to set. If null is passed, existing custom claims are deleted. Passing a custom claims payload larger than 1000 bytes will throw an error. Custom claims are added to the user's ID token which is transmitted on every authenticated request. For profile non-access related user attributes, use database or other separate storage systems.

It isn't entirely clear from this description, but the statement, "If null is passed, existing custom claims are deleted," provides a hint that the custom claims are completely overwritten with each call to `setCustomUserClaims`.

Therefore, custom claims need to be set as follows:

```
claims = {
  a: 'value',
  b: 'value'
}

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims)
```

#### Workaround: `addCustomUserClaims`

A helper function could be created to merge in new claims.

```
async function addCustomUserClaims(uid, claims) {
  const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  let updated_claims = user.customClaims || {}

  for (let property in claims) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(claims, property)) {
      updated_claims[property] = claims[property]
    }
  }
  await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, updated_claims)
}
```

Comment: Great answer @ChristopherPeisert!

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert Thanks for a perfect answer!

Comment: I think you need ```user.customClaims || {}``` if current user dont have any claim before

Comment: Thanks. And since you using ```let``` and ```const``` so in ```for()``` use ```let``` also? please

Comment: Update a bit about **eslint** got error `Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object  no-prototype-builtins` maybe we can use `if (property in claims)`  instead? what do you think?

Comment: The example code has been updated based on the eslint recommendation for [Disallow use of Object.prototypes builtins directly](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins). PREVIOUS: `claims.hasOwnProperty(property)`.  REVISED: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(claims, property)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Since it's 3 years+ now, look at note here (it might already improved?)  (if yes update the answer when you have time please) https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

Answer (score 5):

[Christopher Peisert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57429367/6698132) is correct, but it can be done much more cleanly as

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(({customClaims: oldClaims}) =>
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { ...oldClaims, b: 'value' }))
```

If you want to abstract this logic into a function, it can be done as

```
function addCustomUserClaims(uid, claims) {
    return admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(({customClaims}) =>
        admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { ...customClaims, ...claims }))
}
```

or equivalently* as

```
const addCustomUserClaims = (uid, claims) => 
    admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(({customClaims}) =>
        admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { ...customClaims, ...claims }))
```

Comment: When you do getUser you get a user object, not customClaims. So you should update the answer to be user.customClaims instead of just customClaims. Also, you should validate the customClaims object because it can be null, so doing { ...customClaims, ...claims } in this case produces an error.

Comment: @HelderEsteves We destructure the customClaims property from user using ({customClaims}). Although there is no user object, this stores user.customClaims in the let-scoped variable customClaims. Also the spread operator {...null} is valid syntax and raises no errors.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the abstracted function needs to be async

Comment: @JigarPatel It does not. It does return a `Promise` (which means it is asynchronous in some sense), but we don't need the `async` modifier. Adding `async` does two things
1. Allows you to use the `await` keyword inside the body
2. Wraps the result in a `Promise` if it is not already a `Promise`.
Neither of these applies, so it's not necessary, but adding `async` would not break it either.